# Not sure why my frontend and backend aren't connecting; is it an API issue? Help pls

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios

The issue is that the connection doesn't seem to be going through. The error log doesn't show anything: there's no sign data is being sent to the database. E.g. when I log in, or sign up, I can see that I'm doing that in the console. No dice here.

Vue component:

```
 <script>
import KitchenAssignment from "../models/kitchenAssignment";

export default {
    name: 'sendAssignment',
    data(){
        return {
          kitchenAssignment: new KitchenAssignment('', '', '', '')
        };
    },
    methods: {
      submitForm(){
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/saveAssignment')
      }
    }
}
 </script>
```

Pertinent bit of my auth.service.js file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = 'https://appname.herokuapp.com/api/auth/';

...

saveAssignment(kitchenAssignment){
    return axios.post(API_URL + 'kitchenAssignments', {
      kAName: kitchenAssignment.kAName,
      startTime: kitchenAssignment.startTime,
      endTime: kitchenAssignment.endTime,
      minRoleRequired: kitchenAssignment.password
    })
  }
```

My routes file:

```
const { authJwt } = require("../middleware"); // nothing in here yet, just trying to be sure i can actually send data to database
const controller = require("../controllers/kitchenAssignment.controller.js");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
      );
      next();
    });

    app.post('/api/auth/kitchenAssignments', controller.saveAssignment);
};
```

My controller file:

```
const db = require("../models");
const KitchenAssignment = db.kitchenAssignment;

const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;
//const { default: kitchenAssignment } = require("../../vue-vuex-jwt-auth-master/src/models/kitchenAssignment");

exports.saveAssignment = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const kitchenAssignment = await KitchenAssignment.create({
        kAName: req.body.kAName, 
        startTime: req.body.startTime, 
        endTime: req.body.endTime, 
        minRoleRequired: req.body.minRoleRequired
     });
    } 
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
    }

}
```

Not sure it's relevant, but here's my input area for the user in the .vue component? Maybe it's incorrect somehow.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="jumbotron">
      <h3>{{content}}</h3>
      <div>
      <input v-model="kitchenAssignment.kAName" 
      placeholder="Input kitchen assignment name."
      />
      <input v-model="kitchenAssignment.startTime" 
      placeholder="Input start time." 
      type="time"/>
      <input v-model="kitchenAssignment.endTime" 
      placeholder="Input end time." 
      type="time"/>
      <input 
          v-model="kitchenAssignment.minRoleRequired" 
          placeholder="Select minium role required."
          v-validate="'required|pattern:^(Kitchen Leader|Sous Chef|Line Cook|Junior Cook|Dishwasher)$'"
          name="minimum role required"
      />
      <button @click="submitForm">Enter</button>
    </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</template>
```

Would appreciate any help. I've tried a lot of stuff, can't recall everything but it led me to this point. Been reading up on Apis to no avail.

Comment: **Don't manually write your own CORS middleware**. Seriously, why does everyone do this? Use the industry standard [cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) instead

Comment: Have you added in any JSON request body parsing middleware? Eg `app.use(express.json())`. What does the request / response look like in your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel?

Comment: I've not written any middleware yet (I thought middleware was for extra functions like validity checks and etc.)

Hit enter too quick. It's curious, the Network panel is blank. I click on the kitchen assignments tab (link located on a page for moderators) and see no sign that I even clicked on it.

Comment: Edit: wait, actually. Using a boilerplate so I didn't code all of this, but I do notice some of that in index.js. I don't have routes to this kitchenAssignments page there, but I will add them and see what happens. @Phil

Comment: Won't tag this time, but there's still no sign of life. Nothing's being sent to the database.

Comment: That bit with `app.use()` and `res.header()` is middleware and it appears to be trying to add some CORS response headers. If you didn't know that, why did you add it at all?

Comment: I just misunderstood what "middleware" was -- to quote myself from earlier, I thought it was a term explicitly reserved for things like checking the database for duplicate entries, etc. validation actions. That bit is there to work with the middleware functions (as I understood them) when I finally get around to writing them. @Phil. Is that negatively interacting with everything else somehow?

Comment: It could be. There's literally no way clicking your button wouldn't result in _some_ activity in the dev-tools. Either an error will occur (in the _Console_) panel, a form will submit (in the _Network_ panel) or your action will dispatch and the Axios request will be made (again, _Network_ panel). It's not clear if required but to mitigate a normal form submit, use `@click.prevent="submitForm"`

Comment: @Phil Okay so: ended up rewriting everything, ha-ha. Now I'm at least getting something in the error log (that seems pretty fixable). Just wanted to let you know since you were kind enough to respond o7